# Extend templates through the hook file

Tags: smarty, custom-templates

I have configured the "Custom" folders for templates and PHP
following https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/extending-smarty/

I created this hook file (and I'm sure it's executed)

```
function joomla_civicrm_config(&$config) {
  $smarty = CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
  array_push($smarty->plugins_dir, __DIR__ . '/plugin/');
}
```

in the "plugin" subfolder (relative to the hook file), I created the function.attachment.php with the code

```
function smarty_function_attachments(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {
  $template->smarty->loadPlugin('...');
}
```

but this last function is not performed.
Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see the name of the function is `attachments` and the file name is `attachment`. Maybe, you just need to remove an extra "s" from the function name?

```
function smarty_function_attachment(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: jitendra, thanks for the reply.
You're right on the name ma. even by varying it, the function is not called